# More than 4 paragraphs put a next page option(like Google search result)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using following code 'n' number of paragraphs are printed

```
  <% 

  while(rs.next()){
     String para=rs.getString("poems");
  %>
  <p> <%=para%> </p>
  <!--like this n number of p tags are printed-->
 <%
   }

 %>
```

Know if more than 4 paragraphs are printed, How can i put next page option for remaining paragraphs like google
search results are split  into some pages.

[image: my results are also should be printed like this with 4 paragraphs per page]
Thanks for any help

Comment: You are looking for pagination, and it is typically more a server-side concept than a client-side one. Google for it with the server-side language/framework of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find records set count by using 
rs.Count()

you will get the list of items in result set. devide them into 4 and you can set the pagination base on that.